# Reading a text file into a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

I have text file variable in python containing:

```
A 
-1 2 -3
4 5 6

B 
4 5 6
3 23 5
```

How do I numpy matrices from this text file in a compact way? I have solved it but it's an ugly and long solution..

```
idx_A = read_data.find('A')
matrix = [item.split() for item in read_data[idx_A:(idx_B+1)].split('\n')[:-1]]
            A = np.array(list(map(float, matrix[1])))
            for i in range(2,len(matrix)-1): 
                A = np.vstack([A,list(map(float, matrix[i]))])
```

And so forth..

Comment: did one of the below answers solve your problem. feel free to accept an answer, so other users can see a tested solution, or comment if it they don't help.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Python doesn't have a human-readable, flat file, serialisation format for multiple variables. In the future you should consider the npz format and the [savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) function to maintain human-readableness. Or if you can give up human-readableness, then check out [pickle](https://pymotw.com/2/pickle/).

So to recover the data in the format you have, you'll have to do a bit of manual file reading. This is what I came up with for a first pass attempt, which I don't think is too messy:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

stateName, stateData = range(2)

state = stateName

allData = {}

with open('data') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        #print(line.strip())
        if state == stateName:
            currentName = line.strip()
            currentData = ""
            state = stateData
        else: # stateData
            if(line.strip()): # there some data on this line
                currentData += line
            else: #no data, so process what we have
                dataAsFile = StringIO(currentData)
                allData[currentName] = np.loadtxt(dataAsFile)
                state = stateName

#Process last variable
dataAsFile = StringIO(currentData)
allData[currentName] = np.loadtxt(dataAsFile)
```

Running it with the data from your question in a file called 'data', I get this:

```
>>> allData
{'B': array([[  4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  3.,  23.,   5.]]), 'A': array([[-1.,  2., -3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy` to read csv files into arrays:

```
import numpy as np
csv = np.genfromtxt('file.csv')
```

Note from [`numpy.genfromtxt` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) that `delimiter` is by default `None` or any whitespace.

One way to parse the specific format you have is to use these optional parameters:

> **skip_header** : int, optional
>
> The number of lines to skip at the beginning of the file.
>
> **skip_footer** : int, optional
>
> The number of lines to skip at the end of the file.

Comment: genfromtxt is complicated. How might it be used to parse the OP's data format?